# Do I need an adapter or also a transformer for a Japanese Roland SH-101?

Tags: synthesizer

I bought a Roland SH-101 from Japan (via ebay) and received it to Stockholm (Swe) yesterday. The power connector looks like an american connector and I've previously had success with just a normal adaptor when connecting other equipment that I've bought from Asia that had this type of power connector. Is it safe to just use an adapter?

The adapter is model ACP-100, 91-17367 Tamura-Sz. Input: AC100V 50-60 Hz, 10 VA, output: DC9V, 500 mA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sweden's power grid runs at 220v if I am not mistaken.  Japan runs at 100v.  Most modern electronics are capable of dealing with the range.  Some older appliances are not.

Check that the label near the keyboard's power cord shows 100-240v and 50-60 Hz. If it does not, you will need a "step-down transformer" (also called a converter).

If it does, all you will need is the outlet shape adapter.

Comment: Yes, the AC adaptor says Input: AC100V, 50-60 Hz 10 VA so I think I must get a transformer?

Comment: That sounds right.  If the keyboard is only rated to accept 100V input, then you'll need the step-down transformer to drop the 220V down to 100V